# Using SN74LVC245AN for 5V to 3v3 serial data translation is causing input to not go to 0V

Tags: analog, esp32, level-translation

Integrating a ESP32 with a device which outputs 5V serial signal. This is a device I have no control over and don't know much about (ie: CMOS vs TTL, etc?). All I know is that it has a 5V serial output and 5V supply designed to connect to a thermal printer (9600 N81). My project is to capture this serial output on the ESP32 and also power the ESP32 with the 5V supply from the device.

I am using a SN74LVC245AN to convert the +5V serial line to 3v3 input on the ESP32. The SN74LVC245AN Vcc is connected to the 3v3 output of the ESP32.

When I power the ESP32 via the USB port on the computer everything works perfectly.

When I power the ESP32 from the +5V supply from the device, the serial data becomes garbled. The +5V supply output from the device is connected to the +5V input on the ESP32 and the 3v3 line on the ESP32 powers the SN74LVC245AN. In my mind, it should be no different than being powered by the +5V on the USB from the computer.

I believe the reason the serial data becomes garbled is that the serial signals are not getting to 0V on the 5V. This results in them not being correctly read by the ESP32. You can see this on the scope screen shot below.

[image: Scope Signal]

I confirmed when the serial TX from the device is disconnected from the SN74LVC245AN, I do get the correct +5V/0V signal. When the TX line connected to the input (A1) of the SN74LVC245AN, the signal doesn't go to zero. I've confirmed that the SN74LVC245AN is correctly translating the error signal in 3v3 (ie: the 3v3 signal won't go to zero either). So it seems that it is not an issue on the output of the SN74LVC245AN, but rather on the 5V serial line when the SN74LVC245AN is connected. I've swapped out the SN74LVC245AN with the same results.

The wiring of the SN74LVC245AN is per the data sheet with +3v3 (from ESP32) on Pin 20 (Vcc) and Pin 1 (DIR) to go A->B, Pin 19 (/OE) and PIN 10 (GND) to GND. Pin 2 (A1) is connected to +5V serial line from device and Pin 18 (B1) is connected to the ESP32 Serial 2 input.

The other pins are unconnected and floating.

I am not using any other components (caps, etc).

Looking for suggestions on what I can try to resolve this issue or other things to test?

My initial thoughts to resolve are:

- adding some capacitors to Vcc/GND on the SN74LVC245AN, but unsure of values?
- <s>not allowing the other pins to float on the SN74LVC245AN, tie them to GND?</s> I did this, and not resolved. See my comment.

Edit:

Until I can draw up a schematic, here is the photo of the breadboard.

[image: breadboard]

Wires from unit are bottom right (+5V Red, ? Orange, Gnd Blac, ? Purple, CTS Yellow, Serial Out Blue)

In photo, +5V is not connected to ESP32 (it's just plugged into breadboard by #45)

Comment: Is GND of the 74LVC245 and ESP connected to the GND of the 5V serial signal source? A schematic would be helpful. Even a hand-drawn one.

Comment: A schematic is needed.

Comment: Yes, the GNDs are all tied together. The serial signal source GND and the ESP. I was back onsite this morning and tied all the inputs (A2-A8) on chip to GND to see if this would resolve the issue, but I out some more strangeness. Now, with the scope connected to the +5V serial line everything works fine. If I disconnect the scope, I get bad data again. With the scope connected to the 3v3 (B1) line out of the SN74LVC245AN  I get bad data again. The 3v3 signal on the scope shows going from 3.92V to -1.36V on the input to the ESP32.

Comment: Check if there is current flowing through the ground connection between the serial device and the ESP32.

Comment: @JonathanS -- I can do that. Won't be able to until tomorrow though. So, just get current measurement from all the grounds on the ESP32 chip and the black ground wire out of the device?

Comment: Exactly. Another thing you should measure is the voltage between the ground of the 74LVC245 and the ground of the device (measured right at the device, after all the wires). There might be excessive voltage drop on the ground connection.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to make sure it had good ground on bar.

Comment: @JonathanS only had my scope with me, no meter. Will be back tomorrow with meter to test these things. Thanks.

Comment: @greybeard, not seeing it. Yellow and orange from the black wiring bottom right are connected to middle blue bar.  White flexible wire  going from blue bar to GND on esp32. Which one do you think is not connected?

Comment: (Both yellow and orange connect to row 47, row 48 goes unconnected.)(Just read "purple" in the legend, can barely see any difference in hue in the image.)

Comment: @greybeard, correct. Row 48 remains unconnected from device. Not sure what the signal is on that wire. Row 50 I think is CTS, no output with that pulled high.

Comment: Um, perusing [DevKitC-1 docs](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/hw-reference/esp32s2/user-guide-s2-devkitc-1.html), it would seem you connect to (1?) "USB port pin". Shouldn't "serial" be connected to the UART?

Comment: I am using Serial2 on the ESP32S3 is Pin 19/20 per the SerialHardware.h file I referenced. I know I have the right serial port, because when powered via USBC port everything works fine for whatever reason. I'm thinking I'm going to start with some bypass caps close to the SN74 and make  the other measurements @JonathanS suggested.